# Super Laggy when moving vertices, in edit mode, where it shouldn't be laggy

Tags: performance

I'm a new modeler here, and its been pretty smooth, until now. I have been working a Dodge Challenger for the past couple of weeks, with almost no speed bumps or anything. With subsurf, The total model adds up to 235k tris, 117k faces, and 123k verts. I upgraded my GeForce driver to 457.xx.  Didn't open blender until the next day. The next day, I tried to move a vertice in edit mode with sub surf set to 2. It was VERY slow. About 2 fps. For the record, it didn't do this before, so it's not my laptop. My laptop has a 2-core i5-7200U, with a 2gb GeForce 940mx, and 12 gb RAM.

I tested on two different computers, both having the same outcome. First, my dads laptop with a similar build. Super laggy when Trying to edit a vertice in edit mode with sub-surf. Then, our desktop, with an older i7, 6gb GeForce GTX1060, and 16 gb RAM. Same outcome.

I dont know what to do at this point. 250k tris shouldnt be laggy, but it is. Or , im stupid, and it should. I just remember editing the whole 200k face mesh with sub surf visible.

Also for the record, the model was made in 2.79x. Yes, I know. I opened it the most recent version, and it still  did it.

If yall can help, or just tell me it is what it is, id be happy.

Comment: Moving stuff will be LAGGY if you have a modifier, maybe try disable the viewport view?

Comment: Thankyou for responding, but that wasnt the issue. It was actually the shrink - wrap modifier. I made some small side markers, tried to shrink wrap them to the side of the car, and the main car mesh lagged when i tried to edit it's verticies. I disabled the modifiers so its not laggy, but I would like to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. Its the shrink-wrap modifier I used for the side markers.

Comment: Give more details as to what's wrong about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't. No matter the size of the base and target mesh , it lags. Specifically, its the mesh that was targeted( the mesh that is getting something else shrink wrapped to it) is what's lagging when i try to edit its geometry, not the base mesh. I model a small plane, give it some depth, add the Shrink-wrap modifier, eyedrop select the target mesh, and make it visible. I try to edit geometry on the target mesh, and it heavily lags. Those are the steps I took. I tried to explain it.